# SQL Server: subtract or sum between rows in the same column then update the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table my MS SQL Server, which has a standard row type `BID`. I want to subtract all the row type `ASK` from `BID` in column `availableAmount` then update the result into the `BID` row at the same column. At the same time, I want to calculate the sum of `fulfilledAmount` of row type `ASK` then update the result into the same column of row type `BID`. I'm still learning SQL but is it possible to do this complicate process?

**EDIT**

Example:

Before execution:

```
id   | type | availableAmount | fulfilledAmount | 
-----+------+-----------------+-----------------+
abcv | ASK  | 500             | 500             | 
xyzs | ASK  | 600             | 600             | 
scwd | BID  | 10000           | 0               | 
cd21 | ASK  | 1300            | 1300            |
sadc | ASK  | 3400            | 3400            |
2w3e | ASK  | 2500            | 2500            |
```

After execution:

```
id   | type | availableAmount | fulfilledAmount | 
-----+------+-----------------+-----------------+
abcv | ASK  | 500             | 500             | 
xyzs | ASK  | 600             | 600             | 
scwd | BID  | 1700            | 8300            | 
cd21 | ASK  | 1300            | 1300            |
sadc | ASK  | 3400            | 3400            |
2w3e | ASK  | 2500            | 2500            |
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data *as a text table* in the question.  Then provide the results that you want.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct, you need something in the line of:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET availableAmount = availableAmount - (
        SELECT SUM(availableAmount)
        FROM myTable
        WHERE TYPE = 'ASK'
        )
    ,fulfilledAmount = (
        SELECT SUM(fulfilledAmount)
        FROM myTable
        WHERE TYPE = 'ASK'
        )
WHERE TYPE = 'BID'
AND ID ='scwd'
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question, hope it is clear now

Comment: @HoàngNguyễn, ok then I believe my answer is what you are looking for

Comment: WHERE TYPE = 'ASK' AND <the criterion for selecting which rows to SUM>

Comment: @apomene, by the way, does it work if I combine a query to insert more rows and execute the update query at the same time? Or I have to do this in 2 separate queries?